# SPCrossListQuery fails to bring back results

Tags: sharepoint, caml, spweb

I am calling `SPWeb.GetSiteData(anSpCrossListQuery)`.

It fails to bring back any results or any errors when I call it with an accidental space at the end of the CAML query `<Where></Where>` clause.

Anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is very picky with CAML queries and gives very unhelpful and sometimes obscure errors. Obviously in this case, a simple String.Trim() will fix the problem.

Checking your query very carefully and making sure it is well formed has fixed every problem I've had with this.

Answer (score 1):

Because SharePoint is intent on making development painful ;)

Comment: you are an expert on this matter :)